# When does it make sense to use a struct without a typedef?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Structs in C declare a data structure that associates different data types into a contiguous piece of memory.

Typedefs are a way to create user-defined data type names. This is useful for many applications including `<stdint.h>`

Structs seem to be exclusively used with typedefs. It seems like the default behaviour of defining a `struct` should also define a `typedef`.

Why would I ever want to define `struct` without also using a `typedef`?

Comment: The designers of C++ felt the same way -- in C++, when you declare a structure or a class, it effectively automatically declares the typedef.  But C still does things the old way.  If you want the typedef, you have to declare it yourself, and if you like to type `struct` every time you refer to a structure type, you can.

Comment: *Why would I ever want to define struct without also using a typedef?*  Conversely, why would you ever want to hide the fact that you're dealing with a `struct`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Less typing I guess

Comment: @EugeneSh. That's not an advantage.  From https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#typedefs *When you see a

`vps_t a;`
in the source, what does it mean? In contrast, if it says

`struct virtual_container *a;`
you can actually tell what `a` is.*

Comment: There is one significant case in C where you need to use a struct tag, and that's when you want to declare a structure pointer before defining the structure.  You can do `struct foo *p;` before defining `struct foo`, and you can't achieve the same effect with typedefs alone.  This arises when you have a structure that contains a pointer to itself, or two structures that contain pointers to each other.  I usually declare the typedefs up front:  `typedef struct foo foo_t;`  Then you can use `foo_t *p;` inside the structure definition.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I was wondering if anyone was going to mention the [linux] kernel's conventions. Thanks for that. The issue is a matter of the conventions/style for the project. Although I generally like the kernel's style guide, IMO, it would be okay to have (e.g.) `typedef struct vps vps_t` or `typedef struct virtual_container virtual_container_t`. That is, the aggregate name matches the typedef name. _If_ that _were_ the convention [and everybody adhered to it], it would be less ambiguous [YMMV]. Ironically, with [arggh] `c++`, we always get `typedef struct foo foo`

Comment: @AndrewHenle because, as a programmer in the 21st century, the software you use to write software should understand the software you are writing? If you call abstraction "hiding" in a pejorative sense, that is a massive, massive, massive red flag for how you write code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle "When you see a `vps_t a;` in the source, what does it mean?" -- you can't do anything with a value of a given type if you don't know what that type represents. Your code editor should be making it dead simple to look up any identifier's definition.

Comment: @iono And what happens if you have to access a remote site accessible only through a low-bandwidth, high-latency connection?  How's that GUI-based code editor going to work for you?  You're not always going to have a code editor there to hold your hand for you.

Comment: @AndrewHenle if you're using a high-latency connection, it's even more important that your local workstation is keeping a local copy of the file and syncing only when you do so deliberately. What an illogical question. You should never, ever be writing code straight through an SSH terminal. Also, no-one said anything about a "GUI-based code editor". I said your code editor should be able to *edit code*. Not text. Code. It should be able to navigate your view to symbol definitions, regardless of whether it renders to UTF-8 or HTML & CSS.

Comment: Saying "you're not always going to have a code editor there to hold your hand for you" is such an bizarre thing to say that I'm convinced people only ever regurgitate it without actually addressing that hypothetical rationally. As a computer programmer, you need to use a computer to do your job. You need a keyboard, a colour screen, a CPU. It's not acceptable for a chef to use blunt knives in the kitchen. Neither is it acceptable for any programmer to use the wrong tools for the job, or to neglect their tools to such an extent that they write bad code.

Comment: @iono *it's even more important that your local workstation is keeping a local copy of the file and syncing only when you do so deliberately. What an illogical question. You should never, ever be writing code straight through an SSH terminal.*  I see you've also never worked with a client that prohibits removing their IP from their own systems, or has locked-down systems that were locked-down without those tools you mention.  Having those tools is **nice**. But if you **need** them to solve emergent and urgent problems, you're limited compared to developers who don't need them.

Comment: (cont) Frankly, if you **need** an IDE to figure out the contents of a `struct`, I question your command of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Structs seem to be exclusively used with typedefs.

This is a mistaken impression.  Structs are frequently used without typedefs, and I personally prefer that.  There are numerous struct types declared and used, without built-in typedefs, by the C standard library and POSIX standard library extension functions, for example.

> It seems like the
> default behavior of defining a struct should also define a typedef.

In C++, it effectively does.

> Why would I ever want to define struct without also using a typedef?

Why would you ever want to define a `struct` *with* a `typedef`? Using a (tagged) structure type via the `struct` keyword and its tag clarifies what kind of type it is, and enables you to determine quickly by eye whether two types are the same.  On the other hand, a `typedef`ed alias can represent any type at all, and there can be multiple such aliases for the same type.

There are some good and appropriate uses of `typedef`, but there are a lot of other uses whose propriety is a code style consideration. Myself, I strongly prefer styles that minimize use of `typedef`.

Comment: Your answer is the best thus far. Typedef essentially hides whether the type is a custom structure or standard structure which might not be ideal. I'll wait a bit to accept this answer in case someone else is writing up an answer.

Answer (score 5):

It's a matter of personal preference, possibly imposed onto other people working on the same project as a convention. For instance, the Linux kernel coding style guide [discourages the introduction of new typedefs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#typedefs) in no uncertain terms.

Though I don't necessarily agree with everything in that guide, some of which seems silly (for instance `vps_t a;` example could be `virtual_container_t a;`: the issue hinges on the cryptic name that is chosen for `typedef` more than the existence of the typedef), in my TXR language project, here are some raw stats:

```
txr$ git grep '^typedef struct' '*/*.[ch]' '*.[ch]' | wc
     25      91     839
txr$ git grep '^struct' '*/*.[ch]' '*.[ch]' | wc
    135     528    4710
```

Lines of code beginning with `struct`  outnumber `typedef struct`  lines by a factor of 5.4!

The union/tag namespace feature of C means that you can have a variable called `foo` in the same scope as a `struct foo` without a clash, which is useful. This extra namespace gives us an opportunity not to pollute the regular identifier namespace with user-defined type names, which improves hygiene.

The cost is that we have to type `struct foo` instead of just `foo` in declarations.

It makes particular sense if you have experience with languages in which class/type names do not intrude into the lexical variable namespace, like Common Lisp.

The above code base, though, compiles as C++, so that throws a bit of a monkey wrench into it. In C++, `struct foo` defines `foo` as a type, which can be referenced in the ordinary namespace.

Another reason is that there is some clarity.  When we see a declaration like:

```
struct foo x;
```

we know that x is a structure, whereas

```
foo x;
```

could be anything; it could be `typedef double foo`. Sometimes we go for that kind of abstraction. When you want to hide how something is implemented, reach for `typedef`. However, `typedef` doesn't provide perfect abstraction.

Also, if we see:

```
struct foo f;
struct bar b;
```

we know that these are necessarily different, incompatible types. We do not know that given:

```
foo f;
bar b;
```

They could both be `typedef`s for the same structure or for `int` for all we know.

If you `typedef` pointer types, but the code dereferences them, it looks pretty silly:

```
foo x = get_foo();
char *fname = x->name; /* what? */
```

That kernel coding style document has this to say about the above: **In general, a pointer, or a struct that has elements that can reasonably be directly accessed should never be a typedef.**

Not using `typedef` for structures has as much to do with some of the hygiene of using the tag namespace, as it has to do with avoiding `typedef` as such: keeping the code explicit, and reserving `typedef` for situations in which we actually need a proper abstraction.

Comment: That guide is a masterclass in everything wrong with Linux & much of development in general. A truly revolting document.

Answer (score 1):

`typedef` is just a convenience to allow you to refer to your struct without explicitly stating `struct MyStruct` every time you refer to it.
Some actually prefer this explicitness, making it clear you're working with a user-defined type.

Answer (score 0):

I never typedef my structs so that they can be "extern" declared in other headers easier.

Answer (score 0):

You ask: Why would I ever want to define struct without also using a typedef?

It depends what you mean by 'define a struct'. Not all uses of struct are to define named types.

For example you could define a variable via

```
struct  
{   double  a, b;
}   dbls = { -1.0, 1.0};
```

Then dbls.a etc makes sense, but there is no named type.

Similarly in an anonymous union you might have

```
struct  ructT
{   union
    {   struct { int a; int b; } ints;
        struct { float a; float b; } floats;
    };
};
```

Here one has defined a type struct ructT but the inner structs are unnamed.

In each of these cases if one was to insist on typedefs, there would be more names to dream up, and more code to type.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` isn't just about saving a few keystrokes - it's about abstracting away implementation details of the underlying type.  IOW, if you provide a typedef name for a `struct` type, you should ***also*** provide a complete API for setting and accessing members, formatting for output, allocating, deallocating, etc.  You're hiding the "struct"-ness of the type from whomever is using it.  Think about the `FILE` type in the standard library - that's a typedef name, usually for some implementation-specific structure.  However, you never access any element of a `FILE` type directly - you just pass `FILE *` objects to various functions (`fprintf`, `fread`, `feof`, `ferror`, etc.) that hide the implementation from you.

If you're expecting the user of the type to explicitly access members with the `.` or `->` operators, then ***don't*** create a typedef name for it - just leave it as `struct whatever`.  Otherwise you create a "leaky" abstraction, which creates heartburn down the line.

Similar rule for pointer types - don't hide the "pointer"-ness of a type behind a `typedef` unless you're willing to create a full API to abstract away pointer operations as well.